# How do I Required text box if radio button selected on form submission using jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button, form-submit

How do I require the second text box have some text in it on the submission of this form if the second radio button is selected?

```
<form action="" method="post" id="search_form" name="search_form">
                <div id="inquryValue-form-item" class="form-item">
                    <div class="form-radio display-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="required" value="" checked="checked" id="inquryValue" name="search_value">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-label-45-percent display-inline">
                        <label>
                            Inquiry ID
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="fepUserIDValueWrapper" class="form-radio display-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="required" value="" id="fepUserIDValue" name="search_value">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-label-45-percent display-inline">
                        <label id="fepUserIDValueLabel" for="fepUserIDValue">
                            FEPDirect User ID
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="inquiry_dateLabelWrapper" class="field-label-45-percent display-inline">
                        <label id="inquiry_dateLabel" for="inquiry_date">
                            Inquiry Date
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="fepUserIDValue-form-item" class="form-item">
                    <div id="Search_valueWrapper" class="form-textfield">
                        <input type="text" class="required" value="" id="search_value" name="search_value">
                    </div>
                    <div id="Inquiry_dateWrapper" class="form-textfield">
                        <input type="text" name="inquiry_date" id="inquiry_date" class="date-picker hasDatepicker">
                        <div id="search_value_labelWrapper" class="field-label">
                            <div class="field-description">
                                <span title="This field is required if entering a User ID" class="required">*</span>
                                This field is required if entering an User ID
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" id="search_inquiry-submit" class="neutral" value="Search">
                </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#search_form').submit(function() {
    if($('#fepUserIDValue').attr("checked") == "checked" && $('#inquiry_date').val() == '') {
       alert('Required field missing');
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I used the following condition but the problem is that when I check the other radio button I get the alert also:
if ($('#fepUserIDValue').attr("checked",true) && $('#inquiry_date').val() == '') {
            alert('Required field missing');
            return false;
        }

Comment: Are you sure? I'm referencing the radio button by id, so that shouldn't happen. I created a test page locally and can't see that happening.

Comment: I changed the input type from button to submit. I am going to try the whole thing in JSfiddle and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah, since you mentioned form's submission, I thought that was a typo. Although, you can keep it as button. You can do the same on button's click event. `$('#search_inquiry-submit').click(function...)`. Then in the else part, you can do form submit.

Comment: hey I had to write the condition like this
if ($('#fepUserIDValue').is(':checked') && $('#inquiry_date').val() == ''){alert('Required field missing');
       return false;
}
Thanks
    }

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [jQuery.Validate Conditional Validation RadioButton and DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084475/jquery-validate-conditional-validation-radiobutton-and-dropdownlist)