# jQuery plugin Validation conditional rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

Using jQuery plugin: Validation

If base_select option class one and is selected and sss_select option class yyy ais selected there should be warning like "can't select one and yyy"

```
<select id="base_select">
    <option class="one">one</option>
    <option class="two">two</option>
</select>

<select id='sss_select'>
    <option class="xxx">xxx</option>
    <option class="yyy">yyy</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

check jquery documentation on required( dependency-expression )

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required

or check below SO link

https://stackoverflow.com/q/1084537/287100