# Validate if radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button

Today I must validate my form, and I have problem.

I have 2 radio buttons:
- Company id: #firma
- Private person id: #osoba

If company is checked I must validate NIP (company number) input as required and PESEL (person number) as not required.

If private person is checked I must validate PESEL as required and NIP as not required.

PESEL id: #pesel
NIP id: #nip

I tried:

```
$("#domainform").validate({
  rules: {
    nip: {
      required: "#firma:checked"
    },
    pesel: {
      required: "#osoba:checked"
    }
  }, 
  debug: true
});
```

Comment: conditional validation might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084475/jquery-validate-conditional-validation-radiobutton-and-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You code is just ok, check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ABZHe/).