# How do I ignore validation only if a radio button is selected?

Tags: jquery

How do I ignore validation only if a radio button is selected?

I have one text field and one radio button.
Here is the code for the text field validation:

```
$("#first_digits").validate({
      expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
      message: "Please enter a valid number"
});
```

How do I make the above validation be ignored when I select the radio button?

Comment: what is the ID of the radio button you are checking?

Comment: Why do you have _one_ radio button? Radio buttons are supposed to be used in groups...

Comment: <input id='no_number' name='have_number' type='radio' onclick="$('#first_digits').attr('value', '');"  />

Comment: if a user is having number then he wont select radio button, but if he is not having number he will select the radio button and click submit to get the new number.

Comment: In the form we have one textfield which accepts only numbers and radio button only for the textfield we have frontend validation, but for new user to get the new number user select the radio button and click submit, but right now i have frontend validation which is stopping to go to next page so i need to ignore the validation for textfield when he select the radio button.

Comment: how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084475/jquery-validate-conditional-validation-radiobutton-and-dropdownlist/1084537#1084537